# LIKE query with underscore (_) using Entity Framework & Sqlite

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, sqlite, sql-like

I use Entity Framework & Sqlite database and want to write a LINQ query to find an appropriate string with a LIKE operator and an underscore.
Such as a query

```sql
select * from myTable where myTable.myColumn LIKE "text _"
```

How to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To stay in LINQ you would need to logically compose the query from supported operations:

```
var ans = from mt in myTable where mt.myColumn.StartsWith("text ") && mt.myColumn.Length == 6 select mt;
```

Alternatively, you can use Entity SQL and compose the where from SQL syntax:

```
var ans = db.myTable.Where("it.myColumn LIKE 'text _'");
```

assuming Entity SQL is supported by the SQLite EF provider (I can't find confirmation).

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
var m = from s in db.m
              where SqlMethods.Like(s.FullName, "%"+FirstName+"%,"+LastName)
              select s;
```

Reference : [SQL Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355235.aspx)

Comment: Does that work with sqlite that the original question references? I thought it was only supported with MS SQL Server.

Comment: no it's just support the MS SQL as you mentioned sorry my bad reading the question badly !